# mysqli_num_rows doesn't find anything

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$stmt2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM link WHERE id = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt2->execute();

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($stmt2);

if($row_cnt == 0) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/doesntexist');
}
```

This doesn't work, even with ids that exist ... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well there's definitely a missing quote on the end of your query

Comment: ik, but it didnt work with one too, Ik that

Comment: I guess the `s` should be an `i`?

Comment: no its a string